# have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>? Android 13

Tags: react-native

Getting Following error while using Deep-Linking into the React-Native
please look into this....

```
Received HALT command code 2
2022-12-23 13:32:49.634 17983-17983 AcceptInvitation        pid-17983                            E  Activity not found to handle Intent action [CONTEXT service_id=77 ]
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.goalster_enterprise/com.goalster_enterprise.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2171)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1805)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5583)
    at haj.platform_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at hai.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at heu.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at hai.public_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at haj.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):3)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5541)
    at haj.platform_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at hai.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at heu.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at hai.public_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at haj.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6039)
    at haj.platform_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at hai.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at hai.public_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):2)
    at haj.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):3)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6006)
    at haj.platform_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at hai.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):1)
    at kjx.x(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):4)
    at kjz.onPostExecute(:com.google.android.gms@224913044@22.49.13 (190400-493924051):3)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-$$Nest$mfinish(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

I' wiill check into the Androidmanifest.xml but Already declared MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Deeplinks doesnt work android 13 as before. You must set your compile and target SDK levels to 32. I didnt find any solution yet for this.